# How to rotate image on click (input type image)

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, button

I have this:

```
<input type="image" value="" id="countButton" src="my image here" />
```

Every time someone click on image it should rotate, lets say, for 90 degrees.

Comment: Can you please tell what have you tried till now? We are not here to write your code :) .

Comment: I tried some scripts from the internet, none of them works with input type image.

Comment: There's no question in this. Can you explain what you want to know, what constraints you have to work within, what you've tried? Way too broad as written...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `css` to flip the image. For the `click` event listener you can use jQuery or just plain JavaScript.

```js
$("#countButton").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("rotate");
});
```

```css
.rotate {
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="image" value="" id="countButton" src="http://dummyimage.com/300x150/000/fff" />
```

Comment: Can you please explain why downvoted. The answer is perfectly correct I think. Upvote from me

Comment: Thanks dude, i'll try it now.

Comment: Not working for me,it just flip it but not on click,only flip, and when i click on it, nothing happens.

Comment: Hey.
Sorry if i didnt post enough details, here is what i wanted:
Every time someone click on image - it will flip/rotate , lets say for 90 degrees.
Do you understand me?

Comment: I explained execly what I want.  Every time someone click on image - it will rotate , lets say for 90 degrees.

Comment: Sorry, neither this is working... I'll just find another way to make something like this.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery to change the src of an image tag

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.flipImage').click(function(){
   $(this).attr("src", "http://blog.retevis.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/New-Enhancements-For-RT3RT8-Software-2.jpg");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="flipImage" src="http://www.cityofchicago.org/content/dam/city/depts/doit/supp_info/software_dev_med.jpg" />
```

see jfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/nkfyk7dz/4/

Comment: There is a chance that I misunderstood OP question. By flip I assumed OP meant "flip to a different image" since the other answer was downvoted. (the other answer assumed "flip" means "flip").

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that is not what the OP means. But we will see. ;)

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I don't know why the initial answer was downvoted, so I figured I'd toss this one in.

Comment: Not working for me, image just dissaper and nothing happens when i click on it's place.